# connected through Ethernet but can't browse the internet

Tags: networking, arch-linux, networkmanager

I have been running arch Linux perfectly fine for the past 2 months with no issue but all of a sudden for no clear reason i can no longer browse the internet i am connected through Ethernet and am using NetworkManager i have run the command

```
nmcli device
```

The output indicates my wired connection is connected and working

I have tried pinging 8.8.8.8 and it works but whenever i try to use pacman to download a package it doesn't work when i try to browse the internet it doesn't work

I have also tried running

```
ip route
```

Which outputs my local IP address

Comment: Your systemd-resolved is dead for some reasons, that's the issue. Check https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-resolved for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the problem down first.

Is it an interface or ip issue? Check it by issuing:
`ip link`.

If you can see the interface connected to your next hop to internet, then issue `ip -4 addr`. Does it has any ipv4 address that you'd expect to see? Make sure that it is not a self-assigned ip, eg 169.x.x.x.

If you can see the expected ip, try to ping the next hop router. If ok, then ping 8.8.8.8. If it passed, ip networking is good.

Is it ip routing?
If you can ping any devices on your LAN but not an internet host, the issue is possibly due to routing. Check it by issuing `ip -4 route` and make sure that the result points to your gateway.

Is it DNS?
Ping google.com. If not successful, the issue is possibly dns. Perhaps your /etc/resolv.conf contains incorrect resolver. Check that.

Comment: Iv'e been through what you've said everything seems to work fine except from pinging google.com so i think it is a DNS issue

Comment: the contents of /etc/resolv.conf are 

nameserver ::1

Comment: Ok, so it seems resolver is supposed to be listening on 127.0.0.1:53. Can you try this ```ss -4ln -o state LISTENING '( sport = :53 or sport = :5353 )' src 127.0.0.1```?


This will tell you if anything is listening on 53 or 5353. If you did not see any listener there, perhaps change that to any external resolver just for testing?

Comment: that outputs the following:

Netid Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port Peer Address:Port Process

Comment: It means that no resolver can be contacted at 127.0.0.1, thus your problem with resolving hostnames. You can try to change that temporarily to say, ```nameserver 8.8.8.8``` then try to ping google.com for example.

Comment: I set it to 8.8.8.8 and that solved the issue but what should i set the DNS to now the issue has been fully troubleshooted

Comment: Autoconf (when DHCP fails) is 169.254.x.x not 168.anything.

Comment: Oops. autoconf is indeed 169. Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected my first post.